# How to export csv tables to python dictionary quickly?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv table containing chemical compounds with their properties and descriptions that I wish to export into a Python dictionary:

[image: csv table]

The above table should be converted into the following dictionary:

```
compound_data = {COMPOUND 1:{'Property 1':'Description 1', 'Property 2':'Description 2', 'Property 3':'Description 3', 'Property n':'Description n'}, COMPOUND 2:{'Property 1':'Description 1', 'Property 2':'Description 2', 'Property x':'Description x'}, COMPOUND n:{'Property y':'Description y', 'Property z':'Description z'}}
```

There are hundreds of compounds in the table, each with variable number of properties. Compounds may share properties (e.g. boiling point) or they may have unique properties (e.g. conductivity). I wrote some code which accesses the compound information like this:

```
compound_data['COMPOUND 1']['Property 1'] = 'Description 1'
```

What is the easiest, most pythonic way to read the table into a python dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do.

```
import csv    

with open('csv_file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    compound_dictionary = dict()
    last_compound_key = str()
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row[0] != '':
            last_compound_key = row[0]
            compound_dictionary[last_compound_key] = dict()

        compound_dictionary[last_compound_key][row[1]] = row[2]

print(compound_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with the help of Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('check.csv')
# Fill the nan values with previous values in the first column
df['compound'] = df['compound'].fillna(method='ffill')

compounds = {}
# Iterate through the dataframe
for row in df.iterrows():
#     Check if the key has already added to the temp dictionary. If available then append else add new one
    if row[1]['compound'] in tmp.keys():
        tmp[row[1]['compound']][row[1]['property']] = row[1]['value']
    else:
        tmp[row[1]['compound']] = {row[1]['property']: row[1]['value']}

# The result is available as a dictionary
print(compounds)
print(compounds['compound a']['property a'])
```